# Jenkins: Delete user using api

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using `Jenkins` version 2.7.20 (installed on some Linux box).
I would like to delete an user using some API from my Windows machine (which is in the same network).

I've tried this command to get the credential details for my user `user1`:

```
E:\>java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myjenkinsserver:6060 get-credentials-as-xml "user1" --username "adminUserID" --password "adminPasswd"
```

But I've got this error:

```
ERROR: Malformed store identifier, expecting Provider::Resolver::ContextPath got
 user1
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar get-credentials-as-xml STORE DOMAIN CREDENTIAL [--user
name VAL] [--password VAL] [--password-file VAL]
Get a Credentials as XML (secrets redacted)
 STORE               : Store Id
 DOMAIN              : Domain Name
 CREDENTIAL          : Credential Id
 --username VAL      : User name to authenticate yourself to Jenkins
 --password VAL      : Password for authentication. Note that passing a
                       password in arguments is insecure.
 --password-file VAL : File that contains the password
```

1. How do I get `Store Id` and `Domain Name` for `user1`?
2. How to locate my password file path on `Jenkins` installation?

I've tried to delete the credentials using:

```
E:\> java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://myjenkinsserver:6060 delete-credentials "user1" --username "adminUserID" --password "adminPasswd"
```

But I've got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this. To retrieve the credentials id:

Example:

`java -jar /usr/bin/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080 -i /keys_path/.ssh/id_rsa list-credentials system::system::jenkins`

That will give you an output which looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/michaelBenin/59ffbf20c87000bb4b2ac88652a70951

From there you should have access to the id.

With that id, you can now access the xml for it like so:

`java -jar /usr/bin/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080 -i /keys_path/.ssh/id_rsa get-credentials-as-xml system::system::jenkins _ someid`

I would assume you would be able to delete credentials by doing the same:

`java -jar /usr/bin/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://127.0.0.1:8080 -i /keys_path/.ssh/id_rsa delete-credentials system::system::jenkins _ someid`

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/YR-ba25BFZw